# Failed ssh authentication without specific reason

Tags: openssh

I am running several devices on remote sites. Recently two of them who are deployed for more than one year started to refuse ssh connections. I managed to get low privilege ssh connection to software agent and collect additional information. I didn't change these device configurations, other nodes who still behave properly run in very similar setup.

Here are debug logs which I get from sshd while making an connection attempt

```
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 4
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.info sshd[6258]: Connection from xxx.yyy.20.1 port 34310 on xxx.yyy.100.1 port 22
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_8.8
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.8 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: Network child is on pid 6259
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug1: permanently_set_uid: 996/994 [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug1: list_hostkey_types: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: local server KEXINIT proposal [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha51
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: compression ctos: none [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: compression stoc: none [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: languages ctos:  [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: languages stoc:  [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: peer client KEXINIT proposal [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha51
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: languages ctos:  [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: languages stoc:  [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256 [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: monitor_read: 6 used once, disabling now
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1 [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:33 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:34 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:34 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0 [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:34 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:34 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug1: KEX done [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:34 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug1: userauth-request for user connectorio service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:34 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:34 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: parse_server_config: config reprocess config len 381
Dec 29 01:28:34 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: monitor_read: 8 used once, disabling now
Dec 29 01:28:34 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: input_userauth_request: setting up authctxt for connectorio [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:34 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: input_userauth_request: try method none [preauth]
Dec 29 01:28:34 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug2: monitor_read: 4 used once, disabling now
Dec 29 01:28:34 intel-corei7-64 auth.info sshd[6258]: Failed none for remoteuser from xxx.yyy.20.1 port 34310 ssh2
Dec 29 01:28:34 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
Dec 29 01:28:34 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug1: do_cleanup
Dec 29 01:28:34 intel-corei7-64 auth.debug sshd[6258]: debug1: Killing privsep child 6259
```

What's unclear to me is `Failed none for remoteuser` which says nothing. I found no indication of what this message means. It is a failure, however public keys loaded onto this machine are still valid.

On client side it seems that few keys are used for login attempt:

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/zzz/.ssh/id_rsa2 RSA SHA256:... explicit agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/zzz/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:... agent
debug1: Will attempt key: zzz@arch RSA SHA256:... agent
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
Connection closed by xxx.yyy.100.1 port 22
```

For reference I also post a `sshd_config` which is very liberal

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.102 2018/02/16 02:32:40 djm Exp $
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.
# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.
Port 24
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none
# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel DEBUG2
# Authentication:
#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
MaxAuthTries 3
#MaxSessions 10
#PubkeyAuthentication yes
# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none
#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes
# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitEmptyPasswords yes
# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
#UsePAM no
#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#PermitUserEnvironment no
Compression no
ClientAliveInterval 15
ClientAliveCountMax 4
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none
# no default banner path
#Banner none
# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/sftp-server
# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

Some of answers suggested that ssh daemon might drop connections due to resource constraints, however my `free` output isn't that worrying:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        3878132      973044     2371328       11600      533760     2832068
Swap:         45052           0       45052
```

I ran completely out of ideas and can't get this problem solved. So far I am able to run a rundeck and execute some commands with elevated permissions, however I can't get ssh connection back to work to complete device update. Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: The server is supposed to send a list of supported authentication methods to the client, which is missing here. Can you compare the `sshd_config` with one from a working system? It should show some difference in the authn configuration.

Comment: Have the ssh packages on either type of system been updated since it worked the last time?

Comment: @Haxiel - I compared sshd config and it was same, I enabled `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` after this in a hope to get authentication methods listed.
@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - packages were not updated. They differ in version between systems. Version in affected device was 7.9p1, I'll be updating it to 8.3

Comment: Thanks to Thorbjørn suggestion I updated openssh. After upgrade whole thing started to work as 8.3 properly proceeded to public key authentication after "failed none" sequence. After cleaning the log output I found small differences, however none of them could justify major change in behavior.